# Rester installation is failing from github (rest api testing framework - python)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, github-for-windows

I am trying to install Rester framework (Python) from

https://github.com/chitamoor/rester

Tried running mentioned command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/chitamoor/Rester.git@master
```

It fails with below error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/chitamoor/Rester.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/chitamoor/Rester.git (to master) to c:\users\bhushb1\appdata\local\temp\pip-4m57t3hj-build
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/chitamoor/Rester.git C:\Users\bhushb1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4m57t3hj-build
Cannot find command 'git'
```

Can somebody please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rester](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rester) is at PyPI so you can install it with just

```
pip install Rester
```

To install from git URLs you need to install program [git](https://gitforwindows.org/).

Comment: Thanks.. tried same and it worked... Thanks a lot !!